# Not able to select buttons with class ".button" with the help of "document.querySelectorAll" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my current code:

```js
let variable = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
variable.classList.toggle("darkbuttons");
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="textfield" type="text" placeholder="RESULT" name="text" id="result">

  <input class="C" type="reset" value="AC" title=" All Clear">
  <button type="button" class="adjust button" title="clear" onclick="text.value =text.value.toString().slice(0,-1)">DE</button>
  <button type="button" id="f" class="button" onclick="text.value += '.'">.</button>
  <button type="button" id="2" class="button" onclick="text.value += '/'">/</button>
  <button type="button" id="3" class="button" onclick="text.value += 1">1</button>
  <button type="button" id="4" class="button" onclick="text.value += 2">2</button>
  <button type="button" id="5" class="button" onclick="text.value += 3">3</button>
  <button type="button" id="6" class="button" onclick="text.value += '+'">+</button>
  <button type="button" id="7" class="button" onclick="text.value += 4">4</button>
  <button type="button" id="8" class="button" onclick="text.value += 5">5</button>
  <button type="button" id="9" class="button" onclick="text.value += 6">6</button>
  <button type="button" id="10" class="button" onclick="text.value += '-'">-</button>
  <button type="button" id="11" class="button" onclick="text.value += 7">7</button>
  <button type="button" id="12" class="button" onclick="text.value += 8">8</button>
  <button type="button" id="13" class="button" onclick="text.value += 9">9</button>
  <button type="button" id="14" class="button" onclick="text.value += '*'">*</button>
  <button type="button" id="15" class="button" onclick="text.value += '00'">00</button>
  <button type="button" id="16" class="button" onclick="text.value += 0">0</button>
  <button type="button" id="17" class="button equals" onclick="calc()">=</button>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-half-stroke" onclick="change()" id="fas" title="switch to dark mode">Darkmode</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin" id="fab" title="visit profile"> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ayush-sharma-a155a8267"> Linked in</a> </i>
</form>
```

Why am I not able to select the buttons with class `.button` with `querySelectorAll()`, though I am able to select them with `getElementById()`; here I am trying to change the CSS class of my html elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each button, because document.querySelectorAll() returns an array of elements.
getElementById() returns a single element.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.classList.toggle("darkbuttons");
});
```

```css
.darkbuttons {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="textfield" type="text" placeholder="RESULT" name="text" id="result">
  <input class="C" type="reset" value="AC" title=" All Clear">
  <button type="button" class="adjust button" title="clear" onclick="text.value =text.value.toString().slice(0,-1)">DE</button>
  <button type="button" id="f" class="button" onclick="text.value += '.'">.</button>
  <button type="button" id="2" class="button" onclick="text.value += '/'">/</button>
  <button type="button" id="3" class="button" onclick="text.value += 1">1</button>
  <button type="button" id="4" class="button" onclick="text.value += 2">2</button>
  <button type="button" id="5" class="button" onclick="text.value += 3">3</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yes it worked thankyou i gave each button a id and then selected each button with getelementById which increased my code of lines but now i can do it in just one for each loop thankyou for the help

Comment: "*[I] gave each button [an] id and then selected each button with [getElementById()]*" - why would you do that, when you can - literally - select all of them at once? What are you doing with the buttons that requires an `id`? To be clear, I'm not criticising your choice, but I feel that you're doing unnecessary work, and creating code that's going to be problematic when you come back to it, to achieve an end-result that would have been good to add in the question (please, edit the question) so we can offer useful answers to your real problem.